# Backbone groupBy collection underscore

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app in Backbone with an external JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "r1",
    "hotel_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Singola",
    "level" : "1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r1_1",
    "hotel_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Doppia",
    "level" : "2"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r1_3",
    "hotel_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Doppia Uso singol",
    "level" : "1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r2",
    "hotel_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Singola",
    "level" : "1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "r2_1",
    "hotel_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Tripla",
    "level" : "1"
  }
]
```

I want to parse and fetch it and after groupBy by hotel_id and create an array gropued by level..
I have try this but I have empty array:

```
var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();
        var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model:Room,
            url : "includes/rooms.json"
        });
 var RoomView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
            initialize: function(){ 
                allRooms = new Rooms();
                allRooms.on("sync", this.render, this)
                allRooms.fetch();
            },
            render: function(){
                var rooms = _.groupBy(allRooms.models,'hotel_id');
                for (var hotelid in rooms)
                    rooms[hotelid] = _.groupBy(rooms[hotelid], "level");
            }

       });
```

Return me an empty array of rooms if I trace it

Comment: For starters should reference all variables inside View/Model/Router prefixed with `this`. For clarity I declare them at the top above `initialize` (though if they don't exist they will be created anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it right.

1. inspect your network tab - is the call being made and is the json being returned successfully?
2. before you order your collection, has the collection been populated (`console.log it`)

```
// Define the model
var Room = Backbone.Model.extend();

// Define the collection
var Rooms = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: Room,
    url: 'includes/rooms.json',
});

// Define the View
var RoomsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    roomCollection: null,

    initialize: function() {
        this.roomCollection = new Rooms;
        var that = this;
        this.roomCollection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                that.render();
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.roomCollection.toJSON());

        // Note: Haven't tested your logic
        var rooms = _.groupBy(this.roomCollection.models,'hotel_id');
        for (var hotelid in rooms)
            rooms[hotelid] = _.groupBy(rooms[hotelid], 'level');

        console.log(rooms);
    }
});
```

One thing I noticed was that you were listening to `sync` - `sync` is the method that does the ajax call. It is useful if you want to override the ajax call and make your own one but you should listen to the `success` and `error` of fetch instead. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch